# How to put transparent swf into html/php?

Tags: html, flash, transparency

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">  


<div id="divAnima01">
<object>
<embed src="anima/anima01.swf" width="340" height="590">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</embed>
</object>
</div>
```

Everything works except transparency - swf has white background.
I tried to put `wmode` outside `embed` tag - without result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

http://www.verticalmoon.com/tutorials/general/transparency/transparency.htm

In the embed tag, and also the params tag before the embed.